# Adding columns in MailChimp template

Tags: templates, multiple-columns, mailchimp

I am designing a MailChimp template for a client. I need it so that he can add and edit things, and I need three columns. I use that basic layout, and it displays nicely, except on mobile screens where I get column by column showed. I would like it show fields in this order:
[image]